# Oracle INSTR equivalent in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, looker

I tried to replicate the oracle `Instr` function, but it seems to me that there are not all the arguments that exist in Oracle. I receive this error and I would like to include this transformation in a "plataforma" field in the table but I can't:

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(a.SOURCE, 0, INSTR(a.SOURCE, '-', 1, 2) - 1) AS plataforma,
COUNT(*) AS qtd
FROM db1.table AS as a
LEFT JOIN db1.table2 AS b ON a.ID=b.id
GROUP BY SUBSTR(a.SOURCE, 0, INSTR(a.SOURCE, '-', 1, 2) - 1)
ORDER BY qtd
```

> The Apache Spark 2.0 database encountered an error while running this
>   query.
>       Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid number of arguments for function instr. Expected: 2; Found: 4;
>   line 8 pos 45

I made the transformation of the field that way but I don't know if it is the correct one:

[image]

How can I replicate the same Oracle function in Spark? I need to do just this:

**Source:**

```
apache-spark-sql
sql-server-dw
```

**Result:**

```
apache-spark
sql-server
```

Comment: As the error message states, the function [`instr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#instr) requires 2 arguments but you are passing 4 arguments in your query...

Comment: How could I replicate this oracle function?
SUBSTR('CORPORATE FLOOR', 0, INSTR('CORPORATE FLOOR','OR', -3, 2) - 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`substring_index`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#substring_index) function :

```
substring_index('apache-spark-sql', '-', 2)
```

It returns the substring before 2 occurrences of `-`.

I suppose you want to get the substring before the last occurrence of `-`. So you can count the number of `-` in the input string and combine it with `substring_index` function like this:

```
substring_index(col, '-', size(split(col, '-')) - 1)
```

Where `size(split(col, '-')) - 1` gives the number of occurences of `-`.